# How to login/Register from android to wordpress website

Tags: php, android, wordpress

I am developing an android app using android studio for my wordpress website, i want to add user to my database, i am having trouble for user password, as you know wordpress hashes the passwords, i searched a lot but could'nt find how to write the codes for password in android studio, would you please give me references and resources how i can do this. i think i don't know what i need to search. help me please!!!

PS:
I have no problem of adding user_login or user_email or... to the users table on data base (php myadmin) but i don't know how to send the password. I know i have to hash it before sending, but i don't know the way...

Comment: You should perhaps look into using the API or a plugin which offers an API to the core, for example https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/users/#create-a-user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found the solution. The first thing is i was wrong, You don't need to hash the password before sending, wordpress has the function itself and will do it for you. You need to use wordpress login and register function on your php files on host and it will to the rest for you. In tutorials you may see you need to write the table names and... on php file but for wordpress you don't need to do these things and you just need to write the wordpress functions. this is the code you can use as an example.

```html
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "Your UserName";
$password = "Your Password";
$dbname = "Your Database Name";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

  if (!$conn->set_charset("utf8")) {
      printf("Error loading character set utf8: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
  } else {
       $conn->character_set_name();
  } 


// 


arsalan_add_new_user();

function arsalan_add_new_user() {
 $data = file_get_contents('php://input');
 $json_data = json_decode($data , true);
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
  
  //  Sign Up User
   if (!empty($json_data['phone']) && !empty($json_data['name']) && !empty($json_data['family']) && !empty($json_data['password']) && !empty($json_data['email'])) {
    
    $user_login = wp_filter_nohtml_kses($json_data['phone']);
    $user_email =wp_filter_nohtml_kses($json_data['email']);
    $user_first = wp_filter_nohtml_kses($json_data['name']);
    $user_last = wp_filter_nohtml_kses($json_data['family']);
    $user_pass = $json_data['password'];
    
    

    if(!username_exists($user_login)){
    
     $new_user_id = wp_insert_user(array(
      'user_login' => $user_login,
      'user_pass' => $user_pass,
      'user_email' => $user_email,
      'first_name' => $user_first,
      'last_name' => $user_last,
      'user_registered' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
      'role' => 'client',
     ));

     if ($new_user_id) {
      // Send an email to the admin alerting them of the registration.
      wp_new_user_notification($new_user_id);
// On these lines i had some codes which was related to my theme (not Wordpress) and i removed. You can take a look at your theme register php file and findout what you need to write here. 
                        echo '{"result":1}'; //By using this echo i got the result of register on APP. be aware if you are using Volley library, you need to change the timeout otherwise you got error most likly because the defualt time is 2500 ms and this proccess takes more than this and the APP usually doesnt get the result within this time. 

 
      
     }else{
      // SERVER ERROR
      echo '{"result":4}';
     }
    }else{
     // PHONE NUMBER EXISTS
     echo '{"result":1}';
    }   
   } else{
     // LACK OF INPUT DATA
     echo '{"result":6}'; 
     }
  


 


$conn->close();
?>
```

Answer (score -2):

You have to remove the **wp_hash_password()** from your wordpress source code so that it will not encrypt the passwords. like this

**php $hash = wp_hash_password( $password ) --> 
php $hash = $password;**

here $password is the simple string so u can read it easily or use as per requirement.

Or you can study the Encryption technique so you will able to code a decryption one.
Wordpress use a 1 way encryption to store the passwords using a variation of md5. There is no way to reverse this.

See this article for more info http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-is-the-user-password-encrypted-wp_hash_password

You Should use above code in your wordpress code.

Comment: Oh for crying out loud, **no.** That is nowhere near being safe. It's time to get into and learn from the 21st century hashing methods, one such as `password_hash()`.

Comment: *"Wordpress use a 1 way encryption to store the passwords using a variation of md5. There is no way to reverse this."* - I take it that you've never heard of what Rainbow tables are, have you?

Comment: Linking to a 7 years, 3 month old post wont be relevant in the latest versions.

Comment: thank you so much for helping gagan, but that is not the way, i am sure i have to hash the password from the the app and send it, i saw by my self someone did this before and i know that is the way, but i cant reach him out now to ask hoe did you do this. i know it has a standard way, i remember he told me it is easy and wordpress gives you a method (or function) to hash the password before sending.... but i dont know how to find it...Thanks for your helping firend